# How many Email Alerts and Task can be created on an Object?

Tags: metadata-api, administration, data, limits

How many Email Alerts and Tasks can be created on an Object?
Is there any documentation that gives details about the limits of creating Metadata Components in salesforce?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Email Alerts and Tasks can be created as many as you can on an Object. I am also providing a few links below as they can be useful for you:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_limits_email.htm&type=5

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_wfalerts.htm&type=5

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_metadata.htm

Comment: Hello 
Thanks for the reply but on the links, nowhere it is mention that we can create unlimited number of email alerts and tasks on an object.

Comment: I have added those links for additional informations if you want.

Answer (score 0):

In sandboxes with [Summer '20](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_general_optimizer_app.htm), they've made using the [Salesforce Optimizer](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=optimizer_kick_off.htm&type=5) easier. It's now an app and the information is viewable in your org (versus PDF output).

I bring this up because this can be useful to point out what objects you're pushing limits on and whether best practice is a lower number.

---

To directly answer your questions, there's the [process limits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_limits.htm&type=5) doc which is where I got the info and is **necessary to go through as there's differences depending on your org edition**

1. Email Alerts can be created and not used so you techincally can create as many as you want (that I am aware of). I think you're asking some different things:

how many *workflow rules* or *process builders* you can create on an object (as you'd need them to utilize the alert).

By default you are limited to [50 active workflow rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328439&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1). You can request an additional volume of up to 300. For PB, there's a limit of  total process: 4,000 per process type and active processes 2,000 per process type

*Email limits*. **The daily limit for emails sent from email alerts is 1,000 per standard Salesforce license per org.**

2. As long as you have [storage space](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=overview_storage.htm&type=5), there's nothing stopping you from creating tasks on a given object. Just be aware old Tasks (ex. completed over a year ago) do go through an [archiving process](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328570&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) automatically by Salesforce.